# Can the Doctrine Entity Manager ever provide a null id for an entity that already exists with an id in the database?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am having trouble tracking down an elusive bug that results in `null` values being returned from `getId()` calls on entity instances that exist in the database and have an id.

Please consider the following entities:

Entity `Dad`:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Dad
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Foo\Entity\Joke", mappedBy="toldByDad", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected Collection $toldJokes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Foo\Entity\Joke", mappedBy="heardByDad", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected Collection $heardJokes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->toldJokes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->heardJokes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getToldJokes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->toldJokes;
    }

    public function addToldJoke(Joke $joke): void
    {
        $this->toldJokes->add($joke);
    }

    public function getHeardJokes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->heardJokes;
    }

    public function addHeardJoke(Joke $joke): void
    {
        $this->heardJokes->add($joke);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a list of all Dad ids the dad is connected to through jokes told and jokes heard.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConnectedDadIds(): array
    {
        $connectedDadIds = [];

        // First get the ids of the dads that a joke was told to
        /** @var Joke $toldJoke */
        foreach ($this->getToldJokes() as $toldJoke) {
            $connectedDadIds[] = $toldJoke->getHeardByDad()->getId();
        }

        // Next get the ids of the dads a joke was heard from
        /** @var Joke $heardJoke */
        foreach ($this->getHeardJokes() as $heardJoke) {
            $connectedDadIds[] = $heardJoke->getToldByDad()->getId();
        }

        return array_values(array_unique($connectedDadIds));
    }
}
```

Entity `Joke`:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Joke
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Entity\Dad", inversedBy="heardJokes", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected Dad $heardByDad;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Entity\Dad", inversedBy="toldJokes", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected Dad $toldByDad;

    public function getHeardByDad(): Dad
    {
        return $this->heardByDad;
    }

    public function setHeardByDad(Dad $dad)
    {
        $this->heardByDad = $dad;
    }

    public function getToldByDad(): Dad
    {
        return $this->toldByDad;
    }

    public function setToldByDad(Dad $dad)
    {
        $this->toldByDad = $dad;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function isFunny(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now please consider the following Controller code:

```
/** @var Dad $dad1 */
$dad1 = $this->getRepo(Dad::class)->find(1);
print_r($dad1->getConnectedDadIds());
```

This results in an array of ids with the proper associations as expected:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => 3
[2] => 1
[3] => 4
)
```

However there is some complex code that somehow results in the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => null
[2] => 1
[3] => 4
)
```

The complex code only sometimes results in `null` values resulting from the `getId()` calls. The `nulls` are intermittent. The code in question is inside of a Symfony Command. I am suspicious of the following lines of code inside the complex Symfony Command:

1. `$this->em = $this->doctrine->resetManager();`
2. `$this->em->flush(); $this->em->clear();`

My theory is that somehow I am able to retrieve a `Dad` entity such that it has the correct associated Doctrine entity collections of `toldJokes` and `heardJokes` but for some reason through a combination of calls to the suspicious code above, I am sometimes able to end up with a `Joke` instance that has a `heardByDad` entity of type `Dad` in a state where the `getId()` call results in a `null` value.

I am testing my theory by trying to manually fetch and manipulate entities to reproduce the issue. Thus far Doctrine seems to be always providing me with the full, correct list of ids or throwing an Exception. I have tried numerous combinations of closing and resetting the entity manager, reloading entities from new entity managers, clearing entity managers etc.

The bug I am trying to force reproduce doesn't throw exceptions, it simply results in `null` ids (sometimes) for Doctrine entities that have existed and continue to exist in the DB. Is it possible to have the Doctrine Entity Manager have an entity such that a collection of related entities stores an entity of the parent type that results in a `null` id even though in the database the id is not null? Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: theoretically, doctrine will keep exactly one instance of each entity. So technically even if an entity is removed from database, it should still have its old id and thus not return null. There should only be one case, in which the id returned is null, and that is for entities which were not yet flushed to database, even though they may have been persisted (i.e. marked for persistence). Unless I have some misconception about doctrines handling of removed objects. have you tried adding logging with backtraces?